# Cannot install gem from github on dev box

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, github, rubygems, bundler

I have a gem file which works fine locally.  In my gem file one of my gems installs using a github location like so...

```
gem 'rails3-jquery-autocomplete', :git => 'https://github.com/willfults/rails3-jquery-autocomplete.git'
```

The problem is when I run ssh into my dev box and run bundle or bundle install I get the following error on my server...

```
Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/..
Fetching https://github.com/willfults/rails3-jquery-autocomplete.git
fatal: failed to open '/srv/www/socialu.com/https://github.com/willfults/rails3-jquery-autocomplete.git/objects': No such file or directory
Git error: command `git clone 'https://github.com/willfults/rails3-jquery-autocomplete.git' "/srv/www/socialu.com/https:/github.com/willfults/rails3-jquery-autocomplete.git/ruby/1.9.1/cache/bundler/git/rails3-jquery-autocomplete-186d8dd59401e0d4dd8c2860261d9ba55e0793f2" --bare --no-hardlinks` in directory /srv/www/socialu.com has failed.
```

How can I resolve such?  Thanks.

Update: with the git url I get the following...

> Fetching git://github.com/willfults/rails3-jquery-autocomplete.git
>   remote: Counting objects: 1846, done. remote: Compressing objects:
>   100% (784/784), done. remote: Total 1846 (delta 1072), reused 1688
>   (delta 957) Receiving objects: 100% (1846/1846), 481.07 KiB | 764
>   KiB/s, done. Resolving deltas: 100% (1072/1072), done. ssh: Could not
>   resolve hostname /srv/www/socialu.com/https: Name or service not known
>   fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly Git error: command `git
>   clone --no-checkout
>   "/srv/www/socialu.com/https:/github.com/willfults/rails3-jquery-autocomplete.git/ruby/1.9.1/cache/bundler/git/rails3-jquery-autocomplete-6e048304dc5207eafc457581b1fa2d0073d2e1ed"
>   "/srv/www/socialu.com/https:/github.com/willfults/rails3-jquery-autocomplete.git/ruby/1.9.1/bundler/gems/rails3-jquery-autocomplete-060f2bea5e46"`
>   in directory /srv/www/socialu.com has failed. If this error persists
>   you could try removing the cache directory
>   '/srv/www/socialu.com/https:/github.com/willfults/rails3-jquery-autocomplete.git/ruby/1.9.1/cache/bundler/git/rails3-jquery-autocomplete-6e048304dc5207eafc457581b1fa2d0073d2e1ed'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is a path issue, as you can see the URL is mixed with folder path.
Try to use git:// URL instead of https://.

Not sure if it will work, but it is a path issue somewhere.

Also check your rubygems version on the server, and update it if needed (latest is v1.8.24). There is something different on your machine if it works as is.

```
gem -v
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: thanks tried rubygems upgrade, didn't resolve will try git path next and let you know.

Comment: git url also did not resolve, although it works locally again.  Getting a different error though will post...

Comment: well, that's a progress! I'll check out the next question :)

Comment: although this didn't resolve my issue im accepting this answer because of the effort + it may help someone else.  Also I worked around this by adding my gem to rubygems.org thus not pulling from github.